# How to display array element in EmailJs template

Tags: reactjs, react-native, email, html-email

I have a cart item that may contain more than one element that I need to display in a email using emailJs template. I tried to just display its content inside the template but I got something like this `[object Object],[object Object]`
I would need to know how to write a loop function for emailJs templates

Function

```
const handleSubmit = () => {
    if (!name || !address || !phoneNumber) {
      return;
    }

    // Get the list of items in the cart
    const cartItems = items.map((item) => {
      return {
        name: item.name,
        quantity: item.quantity,
        price: item.convertedPrice.toFixed(2),
      };
    });

    // Calculate the total price of all items in the cart
    const totalPriceFormatted = totalPrice.toFixed(2);

    // Prepare the email template parameters
    const templateParams = {
      name: name,
      phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
      address: address,
      items: cartItems,
      totalPrice: totalPriceFormatted,
    };

    console.log("template params", templateParams);

    emailjs
      .send(
        "XXXX",
        "XXXX",
        templateParams,
        "XXXX"
      )
      .then(
        function (response) {
          console.log("SUCCESS!", response.status, response.text);
          
        },
        function (error) {
          console.log("FAILED...", error);
        }
      );
  };
```

EmailJs Template that needs to be fixed

```
You have received a new order

Name: {{name}}
Phone Number: {{phoneNumber}}
Address: {{address}}

Order Details:

{{items}}

Total Price: ${{totalPrice}}
```

I would like to have the order details loop through the items and display

```
Product1 name x Quantity = price
Product2 name x Quantity = price
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can display an array on the template, but what you can do is map through all the items and create a single string like so

```
const cartItems = () => {
  let str = "";
  items.map((item) => {
    str += `${item.name} x ${item.quantity} = ${item.price} \n`;
  });
  return str;
};
```

then display that on the template